# How to use components

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vuetify.js

I'm a beginner at using Vuelify.
I'm trying to play around.
But It doesn't make sense why it happens.

I wanted to display "v-navigation-drawer" on the left but doesn't work.

Here is my code:

```
<script setup>
import { SideBar } from './components/SideBar.vue'
</script>

<template>
 <VApp>
    <SideBar />
  <!-- SIDEBAR -->
  <VMain>
    <!-- CARDS -->
  </VMain>
 </VApp>
</template>
```

I have tried to use it from components.

```
<template>
<v-navigation-drawer>
</v-navigation-drawer>
</template>
```

I read the official document and YouTube tutorial and it is completely the same code.
It should appear v-navigation-drawer.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with vuetify but I would make your question more clear about the specific problem you're having and what you expect.  From a quick glance, v-navigation-drawer looks to be a container, don't you need to put some links inside of it?

Answer (score 0):

Why did you use curly braces? In the official documentation the component is imported without them

```
<script setup>
    import ComponentA from './ComponentA.vue'
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice.
I was able to fix it. 

Script tag already existed in another Vuefile.
It disrupted the function.